# Conditional variable not working in html using angular 1

Tags: angularjs

The 3rd line is what i wanted, but not working yet, any comments ?

```
<input name="myFile" id="myFile" type="file" accept=".deb" ng-if="platform === 'ubuntu'" vw-file="newObject.newImage" ng-disabled="!newObject.edit">
<input name="myFile" id="myFile" type="file" accept=".iso" ng-if="platform === 'redhat'" vw-file="newObject.newImage" ng-disabled="!newObject.edit">
<!-- input name="myFile" id="myFile" type="file" accept={{(platform === "ubuntu") ? ".deb" : ".iso"}} vw-file="newObject.newImage" ng-disabled="!newObject.edit" -->
```

Comment: Put quotes around your HTML attributes, and define "not working". What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That 3rd line should be as follows

```
<input
  name="myFile"
  id="myFile"
  type="file"
  accept="{{(platform === 'ubuntu') ? '.deb' : '.iso'}}" 
  vw-file="newObject.newImage"
  ng-disabled="!newObject.edit">
```